# Difference between strophe.min.js and strophe.js?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, bytestream

Do we need to include the strophe.min.js also for xmpp file transfer using stream initiation with SOCKS5 Bytestreams? or strophe.js is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using .min.js, as it is a minified (compressed) version of the library, and has smaller size, resulting in faster download time.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same code. One is minimized for performance (white spaces and line breaks removed). Stophe.js is bets used for assisting you with debugging since it easier to read. Once you're past that step, swap it out for the min version.